# Powershell copy all folders and files with certain extension

Tags: powershell

I have one package on my Windows machine and another package on a remote server.

**The first one is** -> *C:\Users\One*. It contains the following files:

- `adapter.jsx`
- `result.js`
- `system.jsx`
- `moment.js`
- `readme.txt`
- package called `info` that contains two files -> `logger.jsx` and `date.js`.

**Another one is a remote target directory** -> */mnt/media/Two*. It is currently empty. The user and host for it are: $userAndHost = "user@foo.bar"

I want to copy all the packages and files of extensions `.jsx` and `.js` from package One to package Two. It's required to use scp here since this is a copy between **two different platforms**.

What I tried:

1. get all the items within the package:

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\One" -Recurse`

2. filter items by certain extension, in my case they are `.jsx` and `.js`:

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\One" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.extension -in ".js",".jsx"}`

3. do the secure copy (scp) - **I didn't come up with the script here.**

Please, help me finish the script.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you need something like this.
I write a code for you, tested working.

```
#Set execution policy to bypass
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force

#install Posh-SSH from powershell gallery
#https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH/2.0.2
Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH -RequiredVersion 2.0.2 

#import module
Import-Module Posh-SSH

#get all the items within the package in the path:
$path = 'C:\Users\One'
$items = (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Name -File -Include ( '*.jsx', '*.js') -Recurse)

#Need destination credential
$credential = Get-Credential

#copy selected items to destination via scp
$items | ForEach-Object {
    Set-SCPFile -ComputerName 'SCP-SERVER-HOST-HERE' -Credential $credential -RemotePath '/mnt/media/Two' -LocalFile "$path\$_"
}
```

Hope this helps you